# Excel VBA group by issue

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

ive been working on a group by function however ive run into an issue, because when the macro comes across a sheet with one row then it throws an exception at the commented line below when really it should escape if it cant group a row.

Im sure its probably an easy fix but ive tried a few workarounds such as elseif conditions but I can't quite find a fix

VBA Code:

```
  Dim gruRng As Range
  Dim gruVari As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long

  With ActiveSheet
        On Error Resume Next
        ' expand all groups on sheet
        .Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=8
        ' remove any existing groups
        .Rows.Ungroup
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set gruRng = .Range("T4", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With
   
    With gruRng
        'identify common groups in column S (Job No)
        j = 1
        gruVari = .Cells(j, 1).Value
       
        For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
           If gruVari <> .Cells(i, 1) Then
             ' Column S (Job No) has changed, create group
              gruVari = .Cells(i, 1)
              If i > j + 1 Then
                 .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group ' <- Throws exception here: Application-defined or object defined error
              End If
              j = i
              gruVari = .Cells(j, 1).Value
           End If
        Next
       
         'create last group
         If i > j Then
            .Cells(j + 1, 1).Resize(i - j - 1, 1).Rows.Group
         End If
        ' collapse all groups
        .Parent.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
```

Comment: It's unclear which line. Have you tried to debug by adding message boxes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement

Comment: @FlexYourData Thanks that worked fine